# Reset milliseconds to zero every 10 seconds

Tags: java, android

How can I reset the currentTimeMillis() to zero after reaching 10 seconds?

```
int  i  = 0;
while ( i != 10) {
    i  =  (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) % 60;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Milliseconds keeps counting even though the app is dead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or instead of using currentTimeMillis why not use nanotime. Like this

```
 long globalStartTime = System.nanoTime();
    float currentTime = 0;
    while ( currentTime < 10){
         currentTime = (System.nanoTime() - globalStartTime) /  1000000000f;
        System.out.println(currentTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You don't have control over the value generated by `System.currentTimeMillis()`, at least not without resetting the system clock, or serious tomfoolery. It returns the current time.

Answer (score 3):

System.currentTimeMillis() is the system time clock of the device and so it keeps running after app is dead.

If you want to measure time interval between 2 events define 2 calenders c1 and c2 for the 2 events. Then set both to System.currentTimeMillis().Then subtract one from the other

```
   Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance():
   Calendar c2=Calendar.getInstance(): 
   OnEvent1{c1=System.currentTimeMillis();
   }
   OnEvent2{c2=System.currentTimeMillis();}
   long intervalInMillis=c1.getTimeInMillis-c2.getTimeInMillis;
```

Answer (score 2):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` counts milliseconds since 1970. If you would like to count starting from the lunch of you program I would suggest to record milliseconds and lunch time and subtract every time you get new measurement.

Answer (score 1):

```
int  i  = 0;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
while ( i != 10) {
    i  =  Calendar.MILLISECOND;
    System.out.println(i);
   if(i==10)
           cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); 
}
```